# ranlib missing compiling GNU bash on iOS

Tags: ios, makefile, arm, binutils, darwin

I'm trying to compile GNU bash 4.3.30 *on* (and for) my iPad 2, iOS 8.4 using Clang, ld64, cctools, GNU make and the iOS 8.1 SDK. When processing libintl, cctools' ar "can't find or exec: /usr/bin/ranlib", causing make to exit with error 1.

```
$ make
(...)
rm -f libintl.a
ar cr libintl.a bindtextdom.o dcgettext.o dgettext.o gettext.o finddomain.o loadmsgcat.o localealias.o textdomain.o l10flist.o explodename.o dcigettext.o dcngettext.o dngettext.o ngettext.o plural.o plural-exp.o localcharset.o relocatable.o localename.o log.o osdep.o intl-compat.o
fatal error: ar: can't find or exec: /usr/bin/ranlib (No such file or directory)
ar: internal ranlib command failed
make[1]: *** [libintl.a] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/private/var/mobile/bash-4.3.30/lib/intl'
make: *** [lib/intl/libintl.a] Error 1

$ echo $CC
clang --sysroot /var/mobile/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk -v
$ clang --version
clang version 3.5.0 (trunk)
Target: armv7-apple-darwin-14.0.0
Thread model: posix
$ ld -v
@(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-
configured to support archs: i386 x86_64 armv4t armv5 armv6 armv7 armv7f armv7k armv8 arm64 arm64v8
$ which ranlib
$ ranlib
-sh: ranlib: command not found
$ find / -name ranlib
$
```

Apparently, my iPad has no ranlib. So, where can I find one? I've tried the ranlib.sh script from GNU binutils, which simply does `ar s "$1"`, but then make tells me `ar: no archive specified`. Or is there any way to compile GNU bash 4.3.30 without it?

Comment: Did you ever get it to compile successfully? I want to do something similar, but for iOS 6.

Comment: @Dan no, I gave up rather quickly, but I don't remember what conclusions I drew. However, the `org.coolstar.cctools` package from the BigBoss repo seems to include ranlib.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I tried compiling 4.2 a year ago or so with no success either.

Answer (score 1):

ranlib creates an index for libraries. It is *possible* this isn't needed or Apple libraries are different than POSIX libraries.

So following a hint from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/glibtool/libtool_3.html you can try creating `/usr/bin/ranlib` as such:

```
#!/bin/sh
ar cru $@
```

And of course `chmod +x` it. If $@ contains ranlib options such as `-q`, you'll need to modify the above to remove that.

To keep going in the face of errors add the `--keep-going` or `-k` option to *make*.

That may not work, so instead or in addition there is this is a big hack which might work. Every place in the Makefile that you see `libintl.a`, substitute `bindtextdom.o dcgettext.o dgettext.o gettext.o finddomain.o loadmsgcat.o`. And you may have to put in paths such as `/private/var/mobile/bash-4.3.30/lib/intl/bindtextdom.o` etc.

The last thing to do is just build binutils. That may be a bit tough though.

Comment: I know cctools doesn't provide any executable called ranlib, but I don't know if cctools provide ranlib functionality in some other manner (e.g. `ar s` like I think GNU binutils do). Also, I've read [here](http://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2012-05/msg00404.html) that GNU binutils don't work well with arm-darwin binaries.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like what I'm looking for!

Comment: Nope, `ar: illegal option combination for -q` :(

Comment: Where did `-q` come from? Was that in  `$*`? if so, remove that from `$*`.

Comment: -q was in $*. I removed it, and got `ar: no archive members specified` (the same message I get when I do `ar s $*`).

Comment: What exactly was in $*?  add "echo $0 $@"  to the script before running "ar".

Comment: `/usr/bin/ranlib -q libintl.a`. My guess is that cctools, unlike GNU binutils, expect more arguments for `ar s`. `usage: (...) ar -q [-cTLsv] archive file ...`

Comment: See if  Thomas's solution works. If so I'll edit down this.

Answer (score 0):

The `cctools` package in Cydia is broken, but luckily `ranlib` is just a symlink to `libtool`, so

`ln -s $(which libtool) /usr/bin/ranlib`

should fix it.